# LibreOffice Writer: copy from a "Find all" search and paste to a list

Tags: regex, find, libreoffice-writer

I am currently working on a PhD thesis in law, which naturally uses a lot of abbreviations. As is customary, I want to include a list of abbreviations and their corresponding terms.

All my abbreviations consist of (more precisely: begin with) two or more characters in uppercase. Examples include: IO, EU, ICC, UNHCR, and VCLT-IO. I am thus able to select them with a "Find all" search using the "Match case" option and the following RegEx:

```
\b(?:[A-Z]){2,}
```

Thus having all abbreviations in the document highlighted I can do Ctrl+C to copy them. However, if I attempt to paste the abbreviations in e.g. a new Writer document the output is as follows:

> EULEXCFSPOJCFSPOJCFSPOJEULEXEULEXEUEU

Rather than each abbreviation being on a new line, as I would have preferred:

> EULEX
>
> CFSP
>
> OJ
>
> CFSP
>
> OJ
>
> CFSP
>
> OJ
>
> EULEX
>
> EULEX
>
> EU
>
> EU

**My question is thus**:
Is there any way I can copy-paste the abbreviations so that each instance is a new line/paragraph/cell in another document? (I would prefer to be able to paste into e.g. calc, since that would make it easier to sort the list and weed out duplicates.)

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in LibreOffice itself, but you can save a temporary text copy and use `grep -Eo` to isolate the strings, then `sort` and `uniq` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it tonight when I have access to my home computer with Ubuntu (my work computer runs Windows). But I also hope that someone will be so kind and contribute a solution that does not require conversion to plaintext.

Comment: OK, but all these utilities are available on Windows, through Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux, or Cygwin for earlier Windows, or in many Windows ports (`grep.exe`, `uniq.exe` and `sort.exe`, though the inbuilt `sort` may suffice).

Comment: As I started testing out your suggestion I noted one fundamental problem; that the text of the footnotes are omitted when saving in plain text. And it is in the footnotes that most of the abbreviations are.

Comment: I didn't know that, so thank you for the information: it's good to learn new things. I'm glad you found a solution, which I could never have offered - macros are not my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro that can do it:

```vb
Sub CopySelectionsToNewDocument
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oNewDoc = StarDesktop.LoadComponentFromUrl(_
        "private:factory/swriter", "_blank" , 0, Array())
    oNewText = oNewDoc.Text
    oNewViewCursor = oNewDoc.CurrentController.getViewCursor()
    oSels = oDoc.getCurrentController().getSelection()
    If oSels.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextRanges") Then
        For i = 0 To oSels.getCount() - 1
            oSel = oSels.getByIndex(i)
            If oSel.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextRange") Then
                oNewText.insertString(oNewViewCursor, oSel.getString() & CHR$(13), 0)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

To use it, first do the search to select the items, then run the macro to copy the selected items to a new document.

The new document is in Writer, but it can easily be copied and pasted into Calc.

For something more powerful, the [LingTools add-on](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools) has a component called List of Abbreviations.  It was designed for linguistic write-ups, but it may work for your thesis as well.  The add-on helps find inconsistencies and creates a unique list.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked! LibreOffice was unresponsive for a while (not surprising given that the list of abbreviations was approximately 3300 words, i.e. there were more than 1000 abbreviations). I then successfully copy-pasted the list generated into Calc, where I can easily weed out duplicates and sort the list.

The OOLT addon sounds interesting too, I might check it out later. Thanks so much for your help!