# Is there any way to create an Alphabetical Index populated by a given Character Style?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, table-of-contents

I create a "**character style**" to mark some important words in a Libre, Writer doc. Is there a proper way to create an *Alphabetical Index* defined by **character style** like creating a *TOC* defined by given "**paragraph style**" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Solution**

The standard way to mark important words for index entries is by selecting the word and going to *Insert -> Table of Contents and Index -> Index Entry*.  Alphabetical indexes are created from fields rather than styles.

To find each word that uses a particular character style, it may help to use [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer).

**Advanced Solution 1 - Macro**

To add index entries conveniently, it is necessary to write a macro that searches for a particular character style.  Inserting index entries is described at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=15755.

```vb
oIndex = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.DocumentIndexMark")
```

**Advanced Solution 2 - SDI file**

Edit the index, mark *Concordance file* and create a new SDI file.

Add entries in the SDI file by unzipping the ODT file.  Use a text editor or write a python script to extract words from content.xml that use the style.

Or, extract all words from the document that use the style and paste them into the SDI file.  Edit each row with a text editor to make it a proper SDI file.  Without knowing more about your skills or requirements, this is my general recommendation.

To do this, use AltSearch, or Data Conversion from [LingTools](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools), to set all the words that use the style to some kind of direct formatting (color or font).  Then use normal Find & Replace to search for that formatting using Find All.  Finally, paste the selected values on separate lines as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1165467/libreoffice-writer-copy-from-a-find-all-search-and-paste-to-a-list/1165644#1165644).